# Get one record at a time from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is the function that I use to display the row from the database. The default value is level 1, SID 1. If the user chooses from the dropdown list, the level can change, but the ID stays the same because I didn't know what to do here. I want to get one record at a time, but when I press the next button, I want to get the next row with the selected level. If that is possible, can you give me some tips on how to do this? Thank you in advance.

```
 public void FillPageSpelling()
    {
        ArrayList videoList1 = new ArrayList();


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            videoList1 = ConnectionClass.GetSpelling(1,1);
        }
        else
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            videoList1 = ConnectionClass.GetSpelling(i,1);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Spelling sp in videoList1)
        {

            sb.Append(
           string.Format(
               @"<table class='VideoTable'>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font face='Verdana'>
        <input type=text style=display:none  id=TextBox3 value={0}>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font face='Verdana'> 
        <font size='3'>Level:</font> 
        <font size='2'>{3}</font>
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font face='Verdana'>
        <font size='3'>Sentence:</font>
          <font size='2'>{1}</font>
        </font>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font size='3'>Sound: <audio controls><source src=sound/{2}></audio>
      <font face='Verdana'>
        <font size='2'></font>
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>              
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font face='Verdana'>
        <font size='3'>Write the word here: <input type=text id=TextBox1>
        </font>
      </font> 
    </td> 
  </tr>    
    <td>
      <input type=button value='Check' class='p-userButton' onClick='ButtonClick(document.getElementById(""TextBox1"").value, document.getElementById(""TextBox2"").value);'/>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input type=button value='Cheat' class='p-userButton' onClick='Cheat(document.getElementById(""TextBox2"").value);'
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type=button value='Next' class='p-userButton'
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center'>
      <font face='Verdana'>
        <input type=text style=display:none id=TextBox2 value={4}>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </br>
</table>", sp.SID, sp.Sentence, sp.Audio, sp.Level, sp.Word));
            lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();   
        }
    }
```

Here is the method that returns one record based on the level and ID:

```
 public static ArrayList GetSpelling(int level, int sid)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Spelling WHERE Level LIKE '{0}' and SID LIKE '{1}'", level, sid);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int SID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string Sentence = reader.GetString(1);
            string Word = reader.GetString(2);
            int Level = reader.GetInt32(3);
            string Audio = reader.GetString(4);

            Spelling lst = new Spelling(SID, Sentence, Word, Level, Audio);
            list.Add(lst);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: ohh no, the code... just hurts my eyes... can't look at it!

Comment: @balexandre, any tips to make it better?

Comment: Your table code is nasty. You're using `<font>` tags! Scary stuff, some are even redundant. Consider changing for CSS. You also have a number of unclosed tags. Specifically notable are your `Check`, `Cheat`, `Next` inputs. I'd fix this, it probably isn't helping. Also all attribute values in your table elements should be quoted. `<input type="text" id="someId" />` not `<input type=text id=someId>`

Comment: There's a lot of things that you could do here. If you use a DbDataAdapter, you could get rid of the `WHERE` and replace it with an `ORDER BY`. The DbDataAdapter will allow you to fill a DataSet starting at a particular row in the database, and determine how many rows to pull in.

Comment: You should not create sql statements using string.format since it leaves you vulnerable to sql injection. Use sql parameters instead.

Comment: @user2457767 just one tip: if Webform, never ever mix HTML in .NET a file, if MVC, never ever write HTML except in a View! It makes extremely hard to maintain... please see more example of code, learn from them! You will improve dramatically if you follow this notes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily have an answer to your problem but I do have a few topics for you to research.

As someone else suggested, research proper binding of forms to server side code. If MVC (which I recommend), model binding from the View to the Controller is where you would need to focus.

Research MVC.

Research Object Relational Mappings - if you like .NET, try Entity Framework 5.

Also, look into third party data grids and data pagers.

Comment: These should be comments, not an answer.

Comment: It wouldn't let me comment on the previous thread for some reason. I apologize.